# Error with calling stored proc in Hibernate

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, stored-procedures

I'm struck with an issue where am trying to call an Oracle stored procedure using Hibernate as in the below snippets.

**My DAO class:**

```
Query q = session.createSQLQuery(" {call PKG.PROC_GET_DATA_SET(?, :parameter1, :parameter2) }")
            .setParameter(0, OracleTypes.CURSOR)
            .setParameter("parameter1", "fDate")
            .setParameter("parameter2", "tDate");
resultSet = q.list();
```

**PROCEDURE:**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY schema.PKG
AS
PROCEDURE PROC_GET_DATA_SET(
   P_CURSOR    OUT    SYS_REFCURSOR,
   P_STRING1   IN     VARCHAR2,
   P_STRING2   IN     VARCHAR2
)
AS
BEGIN
 OPEN P_CURSOR FOR
    .
    .
    .
```

But when i call the proc as in the DAO class, am getting an error as below.

**Error:**

```
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'PROC_GET_DATA_SET'
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
```

Struggling to spot the reason. Can someone throw some light here please?

TIA,

Comment: `setParameter` is this for IN, OUT or IN OUT parameters? Why don't you name all the parameters?

Comment: for `OUT` only parameter you should use `registerOutParameter`.

Comment: '?' is for the ref cursor, which is my OUT param and rest all are IN params given with the values.

Comment: sorry, not aware. will i be able to use `registerOutParameter` with `createSQLQuery` ? @ibre5041

Comment: I'm not sure. I just know that the error you're getting is usually caused be mismatch between IN and OUT parameters. Also binding parameters by both position(order) and by name is not good practice.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use this code to call a procedure using hibernate. See [docs](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.2/devguide/en-US/html/ch13.html#sp_query)

> The recommended call form is standard SQL92: { ? = call
>   functionName() } or { ? = call
>   procedureName(}. Native call syntax is not supported.
>
> For Oracle the following rules apply:
>
> A function must return a result set. The first parameter of a
>   procedure must be an OUT that returns a result set. This is done by
>   using a SYS_REFCURSOR type in Oracle 9 or 10. In Oracle you need to
>   define a REF CURSOR type. See Oracle literature for further
>   information.

I suggest trying this:

```
{? = call PKG.PROC_GET_DATA_SET(?, ?) }
```

If this does not work, use `session.connection()`